# Is there a way to find if a cell contains same strings to other cells?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

For example, if I have 2 cells that contain

```
a1:(aa;bb;cc;dd;ee)
b1:(cc;dd;ee;ff;gg)
```

Is there a formula to show (cc;dd;ee) in one cell? Strings in a cell are separated by ";"

Comment: Yes, there is a formula! Have you tried anything yet? You got `TEXTJOIN()` and [`FILTERXML()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61837697/9758194) available? Are paranthesis part of string or no? Can there be dups in a single cell or are all values unique?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Steps are listed here:
[image]

In step4: Array formula below:
Keep in mind that after you finished writing the formula in the cell, press (Ctrl + Shift + Enter) otherwise your formula will give value error(#VALUE!). It is an array formula.

```
=CONCAT("(",TEXTJOIN(";",TRUE,IF(C10=C11:G11,TEXTJOIN(";",TRUE,C10),IF(D10=C11:G11,TEXTJOIN(";",TRUE,D10),IF(E10=C11:G11,TEXTJOIN(";",TRUE,E10),IF(F10=C11:G11,TEXTJOIN(";",TRUE,F10),IF(G10=C11:G11,TEXTJOIN(";",TRUE,G10),"")))))),")")
```

Comment: OP probably wants to compare the strings in cells `A1` and `B1` and return the matching substring(s) in e.g. cell `C1`.  It is unclear though, what should happen if one of the strings contains `...cc;ee;dd...` instead.

Comment: @VBasic2008 Yes, It seems you are right. 

Comment: I updated solution.